# Faster download for paginated nested JSON data from API in R?

Tags: r, json, api, download

I am downloading nested json data from the UN's SDG Indicators API, but using a loop for 50,006 paginations is waaayyy too slow to ever complete. Is there a better way?

https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/swagger/#!/Indicator/V1SdgIndicatorDataGet

I'm working in RStudio on a Windows laptop. Getting to the json nested data and structuring into a dataframe was a hard-fought win, but dealing with the paginations has me stumped. No response from the UN statistics email. 
Maybe an 'apply' would do it? I only need data from 2004, 2007, and 2011 - maybe I can filter, but I don't think that would help the fundamental issue.

I'm probably misunderstanding the API structure - I can't see how querying 50,006 pages individually can be functional for anyone. Thanks for any insight!

```
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

#Get data from the first page, and initialize dataframe and data types
  page1 <- fromJSON("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data", flatten = TRUE)
  #Get number of pages from the field of the first page
  pages <- page1$totalPages
  SDGdata<- data.frame()
  for(j in 1:25){
    SDGdatarow <- rbind(page1$data[j,1:16])
    SDGdata <- rbind(SDGdata,SDGdatarow)
  }
  SDGdata[1] <- as.character(SDGdata[[1]])
  SDGdata[2] <- as.character(SDGdata[[2]])
  SDGdata[3] <- as.character(SDGdata[[3]])

#Loop through all the rest of the pages
baseurl <- ("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data")
  for(i in 2:pages){
    mydata <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl, "?page=", i), flatten=TRUE)
    message("Retrieving page ", i)
    for(j in 1:25){
      SDGdatarow <- rbind(mydata$data[j,1:16])
      rownames(SDGdatarow) <- as.numeric((i-1)*25+j)
      SDGdata <- rbind.data.frame(SDGdata,SDGdatarow)
    }
}
```

I do get the data I want, and in a nice dataframe, but inevitably the query has a connection issue after a few hundred pages, or my laptop shuts down etc. It's about 5 seconds a page. 5*50,006/3600 ~= 70 hours.

Comment: A few things. Replace loops with `*apply` or something else. Not sure why you do this twice? `SDGdatarow <- rbind(mydata$data[j,1:16])`. Why not do it once for all pages?

Comment: Thanks. Getting the first page first helped set up the dataframe and types I think, helped with the indexing, and it doesn't take any real time. I made some attempts at using 'apply' but I'm not great at it, and couldn't figure out how make it work (yet).

Comment: There must be something missed from the API docs. This doesn't seem(in my opinion) computationally worth it.

Comment: I think I figured it out: I can set the # of elements per page, resulting in a manageable number of pages to call. I also filtered for just the 3 years I want which reduces the data. Through experimentation I figured out about 1/10th of the elements download ok, so I set the call to 1/10 per page, with a loop for 10 pages. Takes about 20 minutes, but better than 70 hours, and works without losing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think I (finally) figured out a workable solution: I can set the # of elements per page, resulting in a manageable number of pages to call. (I also filtered for just the 3 years I want which reduces the data). Through experimentation I figured out that about 1/10th of the elements download ok, so I set the call to 1/10 per page, with a loop for 10 pages. Takes about 20 minutes, but better than 70 hours, and works without losing the connection.

```
  #initiate the df
  SDGdata<- data.frame()
  # call to get the # elements with the years filter
  page1 <- fromJSON("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data?timePeriod=2004&timePeriod=2007&timePeriod=2011", flatten = TRUE)
  perpage <- ceiling(page1$totalElements/10)
  ptm <- proc.time()
  for(i in 1:10){
    SDGpage <- fromJSON(paste0("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data?timePeriod=2004&timePeriod=2007&timePeriod=2011&pageSize=",perpage,"&page=",i), flatten = TRUE)
    message("Retrieving page ", i, " :", (proc.time() - ptm) [3], " seconds")
    SDGdata <- rbind(SDGdata,SDGpage$data[,1:16])
      }
```