# efficient data collection from API using R

Tags: r, api, pagination

I am trying to get data from the UN Stats API for a list of indicators (https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/swagger/).

I have constructed a loop that can be used to get the data for a single indicator (code is below).  The loop can be applied to multiple indicators as needed. However, this is likely to cause problems relating to large numbers of requests, potentially being perceived as a DDoS attack and taking far too long.

Is there an alternative way to get data for an indicator for all years and countries without making a ridiculous number of requests or in a more efficient manner than below? I suppose this question likely applies more generally to other similar APIs as well. Any help would be most welcome.

Please note: I have seen the post here ([Faster download for paginated nested JSON data from API in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206957/faster-download-for-paginated-nested-json-data-from-api-in-r)) but it is not quite what I am looking for.

### Minimal working example

```
# libraries
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# get the meta data
page = ("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI//v1/sdg/Series/List")
sdg_meta = fromJSON(page) %>% as.data.frame()

# parameters
PAGE_SIZE =100000
N_PAGES = 5

FULL_DF = NULL
my_code = "SI_COV_SOCINS"

# loop to go over pages

for(i in seq(1,N_PAGES,1)){
  
  ind = which(sdg_meta$code == my_code) 
  cat(paste0("Processing : ", my_code, " ", i, " of ",N_PAGES, " \n"))
  
  my_data_page <- c(paste0("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Series/Data?seriesCode=",my_code,"&page=",i,"pageSize=",PAGE_SIZE))
  df <- fromJSON(my_data_page) #depending on the data you are calling, you will get a list 
  df= df$data %>% as.data.frame() %>% distinct()
  
  # break the loop when no more to add 

  if(is_empty(df)){
    break
  }
  
  FULL_DF = rbind(FULL_DF,df)
  Sys.sleep(5) # sleep to avoid any issues 

  }
```

Comment: There is nothing general about most APIs: they are bespoke APIs written by different people with different goals and perspectives. If one person writing an API provides a more generalizable API such that you can do things like query a whole year or category or both in one hit, then they do so. There is no governing standard to which all API-authors must adhere. If _they_ don't have the endpoint you want, then I suggest looking for formal API documentation (to see if you've mis-read an explanation) or reach to the organization itself for more formal resolutions.

Comment: Thanks. That's a fair point. It's definitely worth remembering that APIs are pretty bespoke things and there is no general standard. I was just wondering if there is a "best practice" when seeking to use APIs'. Like for example, setting a delay between each request to avoid overloading the server. I was just wondering if there was a similar principle when seeking to get data from API's, particularly when dealing with a large number of pages. I guess there might not be an answer, but regardless, thanks for taking the time to give me some advice. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't know of a "best practice" that is appropriate here other than "play nice, pause between requests, read the terms/conditions, get an api token", etc, something that you're likely already trying to adhere to. Unless I'm on a time-crunch, I often set a high-delay between requests and run it overnight, in order to really have low-impact on the server. Good luck!